# Why is $x^a+1$ only prime when $a=2^k$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Subject says it all. I'm sure I've seen this somewhere, so if someone can link me to a wiki page or post that explains, that works for me.

Comment: If $a$ has an odd divisor $d>1$ , you can write the number as $z^d+1$ , which is divisible by $z+1$ , being a non-trivial factor for $z\ge 2$

Comment: The conclusion should be $a=2^k.$

Comment: @Peter  Ah, well that would make more sense.

Comment: In particular , the primes of the form $\ 2^n+1\ $ , $\ n\ $ a positive integer , are Fermat primes.

Comment: In the list of the largest known primes, the Mersenne numbers play the major role, followed by the generalized Fermat numbers (numbers of the form $$a^{2^n}+1$$) The reason for such numbers to have a good chance to be prime is that every prime factor must be of the form $$k\cdot 2^{n+1}+1$$ assuming that $\ a\ $ is even.

Comment: Technically, if $x$ and $a$ are to be positive integers, the claim assumes $x\ge2$.  Else we get $1+1=2$ for any $a$.  When $x=1$ one of the identidied factors of $x^a+1$ for $a$ not a power of $2$ falls to $1$.

Comment: The title of my choice of duplicate target feels more specific than the current one, but its answer covers this question as well. See also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/453805/11619) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/606328/11619) for more discussion and links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $n$ is any odd integer $\ge 3$, then $X^n+1$ factorises as
$$(X+1)(X^{n-1}-X^{n-2}+X^{n-3}-\cdots-X+1)$$
(Note that this factorisation fails if $n$ is even.)

So now if $a$ has any odd factor $n\ge 3$, we can put $a=kn$ for some $k$, and $X=x^k$, and this gives us a factorisation of $x^a+1$:

$$x^a+1=X^n+1=(X+1)(X^{n-1}-\cdots -X+1)$$

Therefore if $a$ has any odd factor $\ge 3$, then $x^a+1$ is not prime.

Now note that the numbers with no odd factors $\ge 3$ are precisely the powers of $2$.

Comment: Did you mean $(X\color{red}+1)(\cdots\color{red}-X\color{red}+1)$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner: whoops, you are right of course! Thanks for that.

Comment: Please strive to help *organize* dupes rather than increase the duplication.

Comment: @BillDubuque: Nobody told me it was a dupe. I'm not psychic.